# PHP session timeout differences

Tags: php, session

**currentpage.php**

**Case1:**

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['one_session']) && (time() - $_SESSION['one_session'] > 1800)) {
    session_unset();     
    session_destroy();   
}
$_SESSION['one_session'] = time();

if(isset($_SESSION['another_session']))
{
 echo "another_session";
}
```

**Case2:**

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['another_session']))
{
 echo "another_session";
}
```

In case2 if I refresh the page after 24min(default timeout) then the session should not work right ?? and hence echo will not output anything ??

But in case1 will the session last for 30 minutes??   will echo will work if  I  refresh the page after 24 min ?? if yes then why??  what is the difference between both cases regarding session timeout ??

**EDIT**: Assume that  I  have set  $_SESSION['another_session'] on the  previouspage.php and then landed on the current page.

The previous page maybe  like  this
**previouspage.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['another_session']="another_session";
header("location:currentpage.php");
```

**Details of Flow:**

I first open previouspage.php then I will land to currentpage.php and then I  wait for 24 min(default timeout) and refresh the currentpage.php.Now currentpage.php  have  two cases which I have explained above.Now I want  to know will $_SESSION['another_session']  expire if I  refresh currentpage.php after 24  min?OR it will expire after  30 min?Can you tell what is difference in both cases if output is different ? IF output  is same(means in both cases session expires after 24 min)  then how can i  increase  my timeout to  30 min for $_SESSION['another_session'] ?

Comment: You never set `$_SESSION['another_session']` so the condition that produces output will never occur.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying but  i have set $_SESSION['another_session'] on different page.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong on the different page, or the order in which you do things. Please include the part of the code where "another_session" in set to your question and add some details about the flow of your application

Comment: Hey I have updated the  question to make  you understand it clearly .Can you take  a look now ?

Comment: previouspage.php sets `$_SESSION['another_session']="another_session"` a string? Do it from the top - set session - check if is set - check time left or something - play with it, it is the best way to understand and learn this. You can't learn coding without coding, without real tests.